# FlutterSlider range onDragging Missing parameter type

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-slider

I am trying to use FlutterSlider (another_xlider). The following code in the IDE is flagging both lowerValue and upperValue with **Missing parameter type**. I am prompted to try adding an explicit type, or remove implicit-dynamic from your analysis options file. The latter I am loathe to do. I have tried the former, but am apparently getting it wrong.

Here is my current code.

```
                            values: const [1000, 4000],
                            rangeSlider: true,
                            max: 10000,
                            min: 500,
                            onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
                              _lowerValue = lowerValue is int ? lowerValue : 0;
                              _upperValue = upperValue is int ? upperValue : 0;
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                          )
```

If I try setting an explicit type as below, I get **The argument type 'Null Function(int, int, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(int*, dynamic, dynamic)**

```
                              _lowerValue = lowerValue;
                              _upperValue = upperValue;
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                          )
```

The function signature is `dynamic Function(int*, dynamic, dynamic)*`. I need to research what those asterisks mean - having only used them with yield statements - so I presume that is part of the issue.

FWIW - This is nearly identical to the example in the another_xlider documentation at https://pub.dev/packages/another_xlider/example (sample below).

```
  values: [30, 420],
  rangeSlider: true,
  max: 500,
  min: 0,
  onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
    _lowerValue = lowerValue;
    _upperValue = upperValue;
    setState(() {});
  },
)
```

Googling has not helped thus far. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I created my project using Very Good Cli (see https://verygood.ventures/blog/flutter-starter-app-very-good-core-cli). While trying to debug, I pulled down the another_xlider project and the problem was not presenting. I created a brand new project using Very Good Cli, copied over the MyApp class, and the problem was presenting again. So, I copied over all the dependencies in the Very Good project to my non-VGC project and updated. No problem. It appears there is something fundamental about the way a VGC project is created that is causing the problem. However, as time is of the essence and in the meantime having found the built-in Flutter RangeSlider fills my needs, I am no longer concerned about this. **That said, I would like to know what it is with Very Good Cli that caused this problem.** Next time there might not be an easy alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a look at it looks like the `onDragging` callback indicates `lowerValue` and `upperValue` are of type `dynamic` (https://github.com/loonix/another_xlider/blob/7fa4c15a4362d25ecf8e2552e27e5799024c715f/lib/another_xlider.dart#L27). As a result, you need to both specify the dynamic type explicitly to avoid the `implicit_dynamic` issue and also cast the value as a `double` (if you are sure it should be a `double`). The following code reports no analysis errors with the latest version of `very_good_cli`:

```dart
onDragging: (
  handlerIndex,
  dynamic lowerValue,
  dynamic upperValue,
) {
  setState(() {
    _lowerValue = lowerValue as double;
    _upperValue = upperValue as double;
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider) to the version 3.4.0 mentioned that

> Since version 3.4.0-dev.3, step type is no longer double, its FlutterSliderStep

seems like the latest dev update is still not in public, so `lowerValue` and `upperValue` are still `double` types. So just define two properties before creating slider and use it inside of the `onDragging:` function:

```
double _lowerValue;
double _upperValue;
...
FlutterSlider(
      ...
      onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
        _lowerValue = lowerValue;
        _upperValue = upperValue;
        setState(() {});
      },
      ...
    );
```

Comment: The problem is with lower/upper value, not the underscored lower/upper. It is the function signature that is giving the problem. Changing the underscored variables has no effect. The problem, as stated above with my edits, is caused by Very Good Cli, though I do not know why and want a better resolution.